# Changing padding of input:focus via js

Tags: javascript, styles

I am using a plugin which is setting css styles to input fields like so:

```
setupStyle = function () {
if (debug) console.log('setupStyle');
MP.style('font-size', '.9em');
MP.style('width', '100%'); // no calc support
MP.style('display', 'inline-block');
MP.style('padding', '16px 0');
}
```

Now I need to change the top-padding of these input fields on focus - how can I achieve this?

Comment: By adding a class to `MP` and handling the actual styles in css.

Comment: It would be useful if you told us what the plugin was rather than keeping it a mystery.

Comment: @Andy https://www.micropayment.de/products/plugins/woocommerce/

Comment: @JavaScript they have a class but the js padding is overriding the css padding.